# Add and remove div class

Tags: javascript, jquery, addition

i'm looking for solution for that:
I want add class (.hide) to div (#menu) to hide them,
then when body got class (.pp-viewing-page2) a want to remove class (.hide)

I do this but doesn't work

```
($("#menu").addClass("menuscroll")) and
if ($("body").hasClass("pp-viewing-page2")) {
$("#menu").removeClass("hide");
}
```

Adding class for body works very well of course, 
body get class after scrolldown

Please help

Comment: where are u adding the "hide" class ? i can only see u trying to remove

Comment: Explain that "($("#menu").addClass("menuscroll")) and
if" why you are using "and if" ?

Comment: Hi ernest, welcome to SO, please take a tour of the help center to see how to ask a good question, in particular how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand the syntax here... But you seem to almost be there: $("#menu").addClass("hide"); if($("body").hasClass("pp-viewing-page2")) { $("#menu").removeClass("hide");}

Comment: What is the use of 'and' ?

Comment: why don't you use jquery's hide and show method?

Comment: I'm so sorry, i'm writing here first time, i use wrong class menu it shoud be `($("#menu").addClass("hide")) and
if ($("body").hasClass("pp-viewing-page2")) {
$("#menu").removeClass("hide");
}`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of what you mean or achieve excatly, but I created a little snippet for you.

Hope it helps.

https://jsfiddle.net/1L81r7v3/

Basically we first add the `hide` class which "hides" the display `(css display:none;)`, afterwards we check wether `#body` has the class `pp-viewing-page2` or not.

If `#body` has that class we just remove the class.

For now you have to manually add the class in the fiddle so you can understand, I added a few comments into the fiddle.